# Filtering angular material data table by mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material, filtering, mat-table

I have a mat table with sorting,filter and pagination. Now, I'm looking for a way to filter matTableDataSource using a mat-select. This is my code [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7w9ajc?file=app/table-overview-example.html)
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same function which will fire on `(click)` event of Mat-Option also like:

And in your shared example you have used `[value]="version.value"` but it should be `[value]="version"` instead because it does not have the property called `value`

```
<mat-form-field>
     <mat-select placeholder="Version">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let version of versions" [value]="version" (click)="applyFilter(version)">
              {{version}}
       </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

<kbd>[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7w9ajc-wofc1u)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks but however this filters all the columns and not just the 'version' column. This might affect my search results. How can i filter only the version column?

Comment: Unable to understand! Can you please explain!

Comment: Let's say there is another column with value '1.0' but it's corresponding value in the version column is '2.0'. Since the filter i use is not specific to one column, this row appears in my result. I want to apply the filter strictly on version column alone.

Comment: It isn't working as what i expect. I updated the code to clearly convey what i'm looking for. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7w9ajc-5jsehs)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `(selectionChange)` `@Output` property and pass it the value of the selected `mat-option` on your `mat-select`. That is something that you can get by `$event.value`:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select 
      placeholder="Version" 
      (selectionChange)="applyFilter($event.value)">
      <mat-option 
        *ngFor="let version of versions" 
        [value]="version">
        {{version}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7w9ajc-pidehb?file=app/table-overview-example.html) for your ref.

Comment: Thanks but however this filters all the columns and not just the 'version' column. This might affect my search results. How can i filter only the version column?